# change flexigrid row color dynamically in codeigniter ajax page

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, flexigrid

I'm working in **Codeigniter** and using **Flexigrid**. It's working fine. For one of my new module I have below requirement:-

```
highlight rows of unread messages.
```

My **Codeigniter-Ajax** page code below:-

```
$record_items[] = array(base64_encode($row->msg_id),
                $row->message,
                $row->username,
                $date_post->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
                );
```

The above code is populating rows. So I'm not able to figure it out , how will I change the row color.

Any help please? Forgive me for bad english.